# How to trigger the Listview behind when Treeview is click?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, treeview, datatemplate

I have treeview inside my Listview like below

```
 <ListView  x:Name="LvItemDisplay" ItemsSource="{Binding itemDisplayList}" SelectionChanged="LvItemDisplay_SelectionChanged">

      <ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Name="dtItemDisplay">

                    <TreeView x:Name="TvItemDisplay" Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding itemDisplayList}" MouseDown="TvItemDisplay_MouseDown_1" SelectedItemChanged="TvItemDisplay_SelectedItemChanged"  >
                        .
                        .
                        .
```

I have click event for both treeview and listview. both of it when click it will popup a dialog box that user can edit that will binding from them.

the problem is, whenever user want to click the treeview user need to click on the listview first to get the `SelectedItem`. if not nothing will happen since the `SelectedItem` will be null.

this is the code behind for listview

```
private void LvItemDisplay_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

                ListViewItem listViewItem = (ListViewItem)(LvItemDisplay.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(LvItemDisplay.SelectedItem));
                TreeView treeView = null;
                DialogHost dialogHost = null;

                if (LvItemDisplay.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    if (listViewItem != null)
                    {
                        //get the listViewItem's template parent
                        ContentPresenter templateParent = GetFrameworkElementByName<ContentPresenter>(listViewItem);

                        //get the DataTemplate that treeview in.
                        DataTemplate dataTemplate = LvItemDisplay.ItemTemplate;

                        if (dataTemplate != null && templateParent != null)
                        {

                            treeView = dataTemplate.FindName("TvItemDisplay", templateParent) as TreeView;
                            if (treeView != null)
                            {
                                dialogHost = dataTemplate.FindName("dialogBoxEditQty", templateParent) as DialogHost;
                                dialogHost.IsOpen = true;
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
        }
```

and for treeview

```
  private void TvItemDisplay_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        ListViewItem listViewItem = (ListViewItem)(LvItemDisplay.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(LvItemDisplay.SelectedItem));
        TreeView treeView = null;
        DialogHost dialogHost = null;

            if (listViewItem != null)
            {
               //get the listViewItem's template parent
                ContentPresenter templateParent = GetFrameworkElementByName<ContentPresenter>(listViewItem);

                //get the DataTemplate that treeview in.
                DataTemplate dataTemplate = LvItemDisplay.ItemTemplate;

                if (dataTemplate != null && templateParent != null)
                {
                    treeView = dataTemplate.FindName("TvItemDisplay", templateParent) as TreeView;
                }

                if (treeView != null)
                {
                    dialogHost = dataTemplate.FindName("dialogBoxEditQty", templateParent) as DialogHost;
                    dialogHost.IsOpen = true;
                }               
        }          
    }
```

`save` for `dialogHost`

```
private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            // get the current selected item
            ListViewItem listViewItem = (ListViewItem)(LvItemDisplay.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(LvItemDisplay.SelectedItem));


            DialogHost dialogHost = null;
            if (listViewItem != null)
            {
            .
            .
            .
```

I want something like whenever user click on the treeview it will triggered the listview behind /click the listview as well. is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manualy select the ListView Item

> TreeView Selection Changed

```
private void TvItemDisplay_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            LvItemDisplay.SelectionChanged -= LvItemDisplay_SelectionChanged;
            ParentItemSelectionChange(sender, true);         

            // Your code

            ParentItemSelectionChange(sender, false);
            LvItemDisplay.SelectionChanged += LvItemDisplay_SelectionChanged;

        }
```

> Helper Methods

```
 private FrameworkElement ParentItemSelectionChange(object sender, bool selChange)
        {
            var frameworkElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
            if (frameworkElement != null)
            {
                var item = FindParent<ListViewItem>(frameworkElement);
                if (item != null)
                    item.IsSelected = selChange;
            }
            return frameworkElement;
        }

        public T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
            if (parentObject == null) return null;
            T parent = parentObject as T;
            if (parent != null)
                return parent;
            return FindParent<T>(parentObject);
        }
```

Comment: I've tried your code its working but I have some problem which is in my case when user click the treeview it will popup a dialogHost and after user save the edit at the dialogHost it will close the dialog. the problem is if I put `ParentItemSelectionChange(sender, false);` at my `TvItemDisplay_SelectedItemChanged`, my dialogHost not working since it does not have `selectedItem` but if I put `ParentItemSelectionChange(sender, false);` at my `ButtonSave_Click`, I can only click the treeview once.